# GridView RowCommand Events not firing when button created with an external class

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Ok The problem is I have a grid that I need to have paging on it with pages shown as numbers 
I want to add two link button to the paging section to alow user to navigate to next page prev page
Here is my code

```
protected void CustomerGridView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender  as GridView
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
    {
        var prvLink = new LinkButton();
        prvLink.Text = "<";
        prvLink.CommandName = "Page";
        prvLink.CommandArgument = "Prev";
        prvLink.EnableViewState = true;
        var nextLink = new LinkButton();
        nextLink.Text = ">";
        nextLink.CommandName = "Page";
        nextLink.CommandArgument = "Next";
        nextLink.EnableViewState = true;
        var prvCell = new TableCell();
        var nextCell = new TableCell();
        prvCell.Controls.Add(prvLink);
        nextCell.Controls.Add(nextLink);
        Table pagerTable = e.Row.Controls[0].Controls[0] as Table;
        TableRow row = pagerTable.Rows[0];
        row.Cells.AddAt(0, prvCell);
        row.Cells.AddAt(row.Cells.Count, nextCell);
        if (grid.PageIndex == 0)
        {
            prvCell.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (grid.PageIndex == grid.PageCount - 1)
        {
            nextCell.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

its perfectly working and users are able to navigate back and forward (and I can see grid `RowCommand` event getting fired)

The problem is I do not want to put the code inside my page (to make my page tiny and put the responsibility to an other class )

here is my class

```
public class GridStyler
{
    private GridView _grid;
    public GridStyler(GridView grid)
    {
        _grid = grid;
    }

    public void AddNextPreviousOnPager()
    {
        _grid.RowCreated += _grid_RowCreated;
    }

    void _grid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = sender as GridView;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
        {
            var prvLink = new LinkButton();
            prvLink.Text = "<";
            prvLink.CommandName = "Page";
            prvLink.CommandArgument = "Prev";
            prvLink.EnableViewState = true;
            var nextLink = new LinkButton();
            nextLink.Text = ">";
            nextLink.CommandName = "Page";
            nextLink.CommandArgument = "Next";
            nextLink.EnableViewState = true;

            var prvCell = new TableCell();
            var nextCell = new TableCell();
            prvCell.Controls.Add(prvLink);
            nextCell.Controls.Add(nextLink);
            Table pagerTable = e.Row.Controls[0].Controls[0] as Table;
            TableRow row = pagerTable.Rows[0];
            row.Cells.AddAt(0, prvCell);
            row.Cells.AddAt(row.Cells.Count, nextCell);
            if (grid.PageIndex == 0)
            {
                prvCell.Enabled = false;
            }
            if (grid.PageIndex == grid.PageCount - 1)
            {
                nextCell.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

then I should be able to call a code like that in my page load and it should create the link buttons and response to click of them

```
var g = new GridStyler(CustomerGridView);
g.AddNextPreviousOnPager();
```

what happens is the link buttons are created just fine but when user clicks them page get refreshed but `RowCommand` never get fired (they get fired of course when user clicks other buttons but not this two dynamically created buttons)

Any suggestion is really appreciated